# How does density of paraffin wax change with temperature in a solar heater? Is there any equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

I need to know what is the relation between density of paraffin wax and temperature in a solar water heater. I need to know the equation of density in terms of temperature.

Comment: I doubt there will be any theoretically-derived equation for this. I think you will need to search to see if you can find some published experimental data for the thermal expansion of that substance, or conduct an experiment yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[Anton Paar Wiki reports](https://wiki.anton-paar.com/en/paraffin-wax/) these values for the density of paraffin wax:

[image]

Specifying that their measurements cannot be made under 60°C because of the solidification of the wax.

While in [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mse/2017/9590214/) they used a formula to describe the behavior of its density in terms of temperature (in Kelvin): $$\rho(T) = \frac{750}{0.001(T-319.15)+1}$$

Plotting them side by side:

[image]